# C++ Error: String Formatting

Tags: c++, warnings

Here is my code:

```
void subroutine(const char *message) { printf(message); }
```

And here is the error I get:

```
Error: In function ' ': warning: format not a string literal and no format arguements [-Wformat-security]
```

What is the error here? I can't solve it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
printf("%s", message);
```

Longer explanation:

`printf` treats its first argument as format specifier. If you are lucky and the message doesn't contain `%s` or other substrings special for `printf`, the message will be printed "as is".

But if the `message` contains something like that, your program will try to interpret other arguments to `printf` as the parameters. As there are no actual arguments, it will, for example, consider some arbitrary memory location as a pointer, and try to dereference it. This would in the best case lead to a crash; in the worst case, this may leak some sensitive data.

(`printf` can even *overwrite* some memory if `%n` is encountered in the format string.)

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it by doing

```
  printf("%s", message);
```

Or use something else, such as fputs() instead of printf.

gcc warns you because it doesn't know the format string you supply to printf, and thus the arguments cannot be verified.

Imagine you call your function like

```
 message("It's 100%s");
```

That ends up being `printf("It's 100%s");` , which is wrong and ends up causing undefined behavio since the format string contains a `%s`, and you need to supply an additional argument to printf that's a string..

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `"%d"` to `subroutine`, you're going to be in big trouble since `printf` will look for another argument.

The compiler kindly warns you that if `message` contains format specification, the program may crash.

You can use `vprintf` if you intend to write something like

```
void subroutine(const char *message, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vprintf(message, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

but if you just want to display `message`, use `puts(message)` or `printf("%s", message)`.